# Why does 3 phase power never fell to zero?

Tags: current

Why does 3 phase power never fell to zero? Is this is because one phase is always active and  other two serve as current return path?

Comment: Talk about lacking research effort...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster hasn't done even the most basic of research before asking.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a trigonometry question. Assume that your system is balanced.

Then you can express the current in each phase as:
$$V_1 = V_M  sin(\omega t +\phi)$$
$$V_2 = V_M  sin(\omega t +\phi + 2\pi/3)$$
$$V_3 = V_M  sin(\omega t +\phi - 2\pi/3)$$
The currents are:
$$I_1 = I_M  sin(\omega t)$$
$$I_2 = I_M  sin(\omega t + 2\pi/3)$$
$$I_3 = I_M  sin(\omega t - 2\pi/3)$$

The instantaneous power is:
$$P(t)= V_1 I_1 + V_2 I_2 + V_3 I_3$$
Therefore:
$$P(t)= V_M I_M (sin(\omega t +\phi) sin(\omega t) + sin(\omega t +\phi + 2\pi/3) sin(\omega t + 2\pi/3) + sin(\omega t +\phi - 2\pi/3) sin(\omega t  - 2\pi/3))$$

Now, by Werner's formula:
$$sin(x)sin(y) = \frac{cos(x-y) - cos(x+y)}2 $$

Then:
$$P(t)= V_M I_M (\frac{3cos(\phi)}2 + cos(2\omega t +\phi) + cos(2\omega t + 4\pi/3 + \phi) + cos(2\omega t  - 4\pi/3+\phi))$$

Now, again Werner's formula:
$$ cos(x)cos(y) = \frac{cos(x+y)+cos(x-y)}2$$
Which must be used in the opposite way, by noting that you can set:
$$ x= 2\omega t+\phi$$
$$ y = 4\pi/3$$

Hence:
$$ cos(2\omega t + 4\pi/3 + \phi) + cos(2\omega t  - 4\pi/3+\phi) = 2cos(2\omega t + \phi )cos(4\pi/3) = -cos(2\omega t + \phi) $$

Therefore:
$$P(t)= V_M I_M (\frac{3cos(\phi)}2 + cos(2\omega t +\phi) - cos(2\omega t +\phi)) = V_M I_M \frac{3cos(\phi)}2$$

Which is constant and does not depend on time.

Answer (score 1):

In a 3-phase supply, the three phases are sinusoidal, with the phases all 120° apart from each other.  If you plot those as a graph, then you find that if one of the phases is crossing zero voltage, then the other two will always be non-zero.  See [this diagram on Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power#/media/File:3_phase_AC_waveform.svg).

A 3-phase appliance can be wired with the loads across the phases (delta wired) or between each phase and neutral (star wired)These loads could be heaters or motor windings.  Either way, there is always a non-zero voltage across at least two of the loads.

Answer (score 1):

3phase power "never fell to zero" because there is always 1phase with a voltage not equal to zero

Consider a 3phase voltage source and each phase and a 5\$\Omega\$ resistor & this was in a star arrangement. Each resistor would be dissipating 
[image]